# Good quality Shulchan Aruch series, in audio or video?

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, torah-study, shulchan-aruch

I want to have an understanding of common Halacha and have an understanding of halacha.
Do you know any good source for good quality Shulchan Aruch series, in audio or video?

Comment: If you want common Halacha in a final form, maybe the S"A is not the best option. What about a kitzur? Are you looking for process, traditions and options, discussion or just compendia?

Comment: We normally don't edit individual transcription schemes, but here Shulchan Aruch is so much more common that I allowed myself to change it to make it easier to find the question in the future. Hope that is OK and welcome to MY !

Comment: What is the difference between "an understanding of common Halacha" and "an understanding of halacha" ?

Answer (score 1):

R. [Yaakov Yosef](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ya%27akov_Yosef) gave shiurim on Shulhan Aruch for many years. His style is clear, comprehensive and practical. I’d personally recommend the classes both for beginners and more advanced. Only caveat: they’re all in Hebrew.

Link: https://www.kolhalashon.com/New/Ravs.aspx?&Lang=Hebrew&FID=65820&ROrder=-1

Answer (score -1):

There is the new [Pirkei Shoshanim](https://pirchei-shoshanim.teachable.com/) site - although please note that there is an associated cost. However, you can see some preview videos to gain a flavour of what to expect if this is something you would want to pursue.

Courses include:
[Hilchos Issur V'heter](https://pirchei-shoshanim.teachable.com/p/issur-v-heter)
[Kosher Kitchen](https://pirchei-shoshanim.teachable.com/p/kosher-kitchen)
[Hilchos Mezuzah](https://pirchei-shoshanim.teachable.com/p/hilchos-mezuza)
[Laws of Shaatnez](https://pirchei-shoshanim.teachable.com/p/laws-of-shaatnez)

Alternatively, there is a weekly shulchan aruch shiur from Rabbi Silber of the Institute For Jewish Continuity [here](https://rabbisilber.com/?s=shulchan%20aruch)

There is a '[daily dose of halacha](https://outorah.org/series/4068)' by the OU that is predominantly driven by Shulchan Aruch sources.

Comment: Can the nameless downvoter have the decency to comment what offended them so much?!

Answer (score -1):

https://mishnaberurayomi.org/archive.php
This has the whole mishna berura in English on audio. I use it myself and can recommend it. It is best to download the shiur then you can play it back at your own rate on VLC. It is certainly 'best' quality.

Comment: I think he wanted b'davka Shulchan Aruch and not its commentaries? Unless I have misunderstood the question

Comment: Well of course he learns the shulchan aruch as well. One cant just learn MB on its own.

Comment: Of course - he just didn't emphasise anything else?!

Answer (score -2):

Rav Shmuel Fuerst has given(and continues to give) numerous halacha shiurim on many topics . They can be found here http://www.psak.org. If you are looking for something specific use the find box .